# Datepicker shows "undefined" instead of month name and day name

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have a page to show datepicker but instead of month name and date, it shows undefined.

CSHTML

```
                                        <div class="row my-row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-5">Select incident date range From</label>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                                        <input id="fromDate" class="datepicker" />
                                                        <input name="button" type="image" src="~/Content/Images/icon_calendar.png" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>   
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-5">To</label>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                                        <input id="toDate" class="datepicker" />
                                                        <input name="button" type="image" src="~/Content/Images/icon_calendar.png" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
```

javascript

```
 $('#datepicker')
 .datepicker({

     format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     autoclose: true,
     endDate: '+0d',
     todayHighlight: true,
     weekStart: 1
 })
```

can any one please help on this..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant $('.datepicker') instead of $('#datepicker') ?

If you have correctly import the boostrap and jqueryui files, you shouln't have any error. Maybe you have conflicts with something else

Comment: I updated with $('.datepicker'). But still same issue and no error message in console